# Channel API python can't understand one part

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to build a chat application using channel API in Google App Engine.
When going through  http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview
I could not understand  the opening the socket part using the XMLHttpRequest();
Any help will be appreciated!! 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when the socket is opened, the code below updates the user interface of an example Tic Tac Toe game, and sends a POST message to the server asking for the latest game state.

The code is not Python, it's client-side [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).  I have commented it below:

```
sendMessage = function(path, opt_param) {
  /* path variable is part of a URL being maintained */
  path += '?g=' + state.game_key;  /* Saving game key in URL */
  if (opt_param) {
    path += '&' + opt_param; /* Adding optional parameters to the path */
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* Used for Ajax in Javascript */
  xhr.open('POST', path, true); /* Asynchronously POST, via HTTP, the path */
  xhr.send(); /* Start the POST above */
};

onOpened = function() {
  connected = true; /* Set boolean value, which lets us know we're connected */
  sendMessage('opened'); /* We can now send messages to the server */
  updateBoard(); /* Update user interface to reflect that socket is open */
};
```

Note that the application defines `sendMessage()` as a wrapper around XmlHttpRequest, which the client uses to send messages to the server.

Comment: so if we are building a chat application,this code basically updates the chat screen by iteself..using ajax basically

Comment: @user1512547 it *can* update your screen if you create a function in Javascript to update the screen. This function is a callback function that is executed when the socket is opened. Their *Javascript* function that updates their Tic Tac Toe board is called `updateBoard()`.

Comment: `sendMessage` is actually sending a message (path) to the server.  `onOpened` is executed when the socket is opened.  `updateBoard()` is a Javascript function which updates the Tic Tac Toe board's GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The socket is "opened" when the channel between client and server is established. At that point the OnOpened callback is called. The callback does a POST request back to the server to get the current state of the game. So the XMLHttpRequest is not related to the opening of the socket but rather is just a common coding pattern to have a two way communication since the channel is just one way (server to client). The other route (client to server) is done through these HTTP requests. Almost every time you get a message in the channel from the server you will want to send something back to the server (a response, an update, etc.). 
Hope this helps.